# Wandering Jew Cutting propagation

Tags: propagation

My Wandering Jew cutting which had been in water for several weeks, has new growth, but no roots.
Should I plant it in soil? If so, would root tone help?

Comment: These cuttings root on their own after inserting them directly into the soil, laying them on the soil, or saying the word soil near them. They love moisture and shade.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait till it has roots that are at least a few inches long, then plant it in potting mix.  Provide good light to retain the leaf color.

This is a tough plant that propagates readily so you should not have any problems.  Just wait another month or so for roots to show.